# How to make a static property observable in C#?

Tags: c#

I am trying to get my UI to respond to a change in the value of a static property. I am using the MVVM toolkit. Marking the static property with [ObservableProperty] doesn't work for reasons that are obvious if I look at the generated code. Is there a way to make a static property observable as if I used this construct?

```
[ObservableProperty]
private static bool boxIsEmpty;
```

I looked at the generated code and it's not obvious to me how I can make this happen. All other approaches that I've found are based on non-static properties.

The specific context is I am developing an app using .NET MAUI. I have a Label control with its IsVisible property bound to the BoxIsEmpty property that is currently static. I need the Label to become visible whenever BoxIsEmpty is true.

Here is the specific context in XAML with all the formatting details left out. "vm" is set to the namespace of the relevant View Model.

```
<Label Text="Your box is empty" IsVisible="{Binding x:Static vm:BoxVM.BoxIsEmpty}}"/>
```

Comment: First of all, that's not a property but a field and also private.

Comment: @Alberto - yes, that is the way to structure the declaration that is tagged with [ObservableProperty]. The public property corresponding to the private field is auto generated when that tag is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's not possible to implement *normal* observation for static property because `INotifyPropertyChanged` has only per-instance members.

So, if you need to handle some shared static state with `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, you will need to proxy such a state on the instance-level.

For example

```
class Test : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDisposable
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
    public static PropertyChangedEventHandler? StaticPropertyChanged;
    
    private static bool observedProperty;
    public static bool ObservedProperty
    {
        get => observedProperty;
        set
        {
            observedProperty = value;
            StaticPropertyChanged?.Invoke(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ObservedProperty)));
        }
    }
    
    public bool InstanceObservedProperty => ObservedProperty;

    public Test()
    {
        StaticPropertyChanged+=HandleStaticPropertyChanged;
    }

    private void HandleStaticPropertyChanged(object? sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.Assert(sender is null);
        if(e.PropertyName == nameof(ObservedProperty))
        {
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(InstanceObservedProperty));
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string? propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        StaticPropertyChanged -= HandleStaticPropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

Here we do the following

- implemented custom static event to notify subscribers about static property changes
- each instance of a class subscribes to such an event and then fire per-instance `PropertyChanged` event on each change of static variable.
- to meet `InotifyPropertyChanged` requirement there is a per-instance (non-static) property `InstanceObservedProperty` which just proxying the value of corresponding static property
- **Important** `IDisposable` implemented to unsubscribe static event when instance is not needed. Without unsubscribing you will get memory leak.
- You may to consider to improve memory-leak prevention and use `WeakEvent` (may be dangerous) or even finalizer to make sure you will not keep references which is not needed anymore.

Alternatively, if you do not need to use exact `INotyfyProperyChanged` but need just to observe static property, then you can just use only static event and throw out the rest of the sample.

Comment: This is very helpful @Serg. Thanks for your time to put this together. I edited my post to include more detail about the context. I would greatly appreciate any guidance on how I might notify the UI of a change in the BoxIsEmpty static property without using INotifyPropertyChanged. This is the first app I've developed in 25 years and am trying to better understand the event-driven mechanisms in C# and UI development. I have solved this problem by refactoring my code to use non-static properties but it's creating an overly complicated design.

Comment: If you are using MAUI then the only good way to notify UI about changes is to use `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Solution without it may be only used with your custom code where you can choose event to subscribe at your own (and I don't know aboyt such an option for NAUI).